# Marklogic DHF 5.2.5 Lexicon based collector for step

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

Using Marklogic DHF 5 and trying to run a step for every value of a lexicon lookup (e.g cts.values). In DHF 4 this could be achieved by modifying the collector but DHF 5 seems to have eliminate that customisation option.
Checking the underlying code, I could get the collector to return lexicon values using cts.values in sourceQuery but then the step fails silently in the runFlow function.

Any ideas on how to achieve this in DHF 5?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately is not possible in DHF 5.0 through 5.2, but DHF 5.4 (due out soon) will allow for your sourceQuery to return any values you want.